Activate AudioSession while app is in background or killed
I'm developing a voice communication App using Livekit SDK. Everything works fine in the foreground. AudioSession is activated, and audio is transmitted. However, I would like to add a feature. I would like my app to receive audio even when it's in the background or terminated. I know I can run code when the App is in that state by sending a background push notification. I made several tests (e.g: writing to the Firebase database, and it works great), but the only thing that is not working in that case is the AudioSession activation. It fails with the error Session activation failed, no more clues. I tried every combination of category and mode but with no success. Background modes in Xcode have been activated: -Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture -Background Processing
Is this a limit of Livekit?
I need to write code inside this function:
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) async -> UIBackgroundFetchResult {
    // Livekit room connection. Here is where AudioSession activation fails
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Ot isnt possible you can use Siri to give the user commands they could use to start your app.

It should be possible, I downloaded Ten Ten from the App store and it works exactly like this

For privacy reasons it's not wanted that you kick of a audio session, especially a recording session, in the background. The only way, I am aware of, is using CallKit or keeping the audio session active all the time.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

If you want to use Microphone in the background. You need to create a Foreground service in the form of a MicrophoneService.
I do not know Livekit SDK but they may have a MicrophoneService internally and you need to call it from MainActivity like:
  private fun startForegroundService() {
    val serviceIntent = Intent(this, MicrophoneService::class.java)
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent)
  }

Also make sure your Manifest has all the right permission.
Below is a good simple example of Android App that always liste
https://github.com/frymanofer/ReactNative_WakeWordDetection
It is a simple wake word detection example however has all the ingredients to listen in the background all the time.
Hope this helps.
